# Align strings among themselves using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I've got a container with some infos within. I use flexbox to display it in a row and `justify-content: space-between;` for using the whole space of the container from start to end. This works fine. The only problem I got is, that the strings dont align among themselves. I tried to set `flex-basis: 0px;` on `.info`, but it didn't help. Any ideas?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.info {
  /* flex-basis: 0px; */
  /* didn't help */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="info">Switzerland</div>
  <div class="info">Norway</div>
  <div class="info">Serbia</div>
  <div class="info">Great Britain</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="info">Zurich</div>
  <div class="info">Oslo</div>
  <div class="info">Belgrade</div>
  <div class="info">London</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `flex-basis: 25%;` works just fine as well (for 4 columns :)

Comment: @LGSon This is how I solved it: https://jsfiddle.net/a04t532k/ (using the correct marked answer flex: 1; and changed some stuff on the last string in the container)

Comment: Ok, note though, when a name is longer than the 100px, it will break line. If you want it dynamic, you'll need a markup change

Comment: @LGSon Yes I know, this is some dummy data, in my working app the last string has a fix length so it wouldn't be a problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the shorthand `flex` rule to the `.info` elements and set it to `1`, which will give them the ability to grow.

> ### [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/flex?v=example)
>
> *The flex CSS property is a shorthand property specifying the ability of a flex item to alter its dimensions to fill available space. Flex items can be stretched to use available space proportional to their flex grow factor or their flex shrink factor to prevent overflow.*

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.info {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="info">Switzerland</div>
  <div class="info">Norway</div>
  <div class="info">Serbia</div>
  <div class="info">Great Britain</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="info">Zurich</div>
  <div class="info">Oslo</div>
  <div class="info">Belgrade</div>
  <div class="info">London</div>
</div>
```

Comment: One question: Now the space-between seems not to work, because great britain end london arent at the end? How to fix this?

Comment: @MrBuggy When using `flex: 1`, or what I suggested, `flex-basis: 25%`, the `space-between` will have no effect, since there is no _space left_ between the flex items. Can you explain how each columns text should align (left,center,right,...) ? ... the `text-align: right;` for the 4th column, `text-align: center;` for the 2nd and 3rd in the middle might be enough

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a minimum width so that the flex doesn't use the width of the strings.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.info {
  /* flex-basis: 0px; */
  /* didn't help */
  min-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="info">Switzerland</div>
  <div class="info">Norway</div>
  <div class="info">Serbia</div>
  <div class="info">Great Britain</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="info">Zurich</div>
  <div class="info">Oslo</div>
  <div class="info">Belgrade</div>
  <div class="info">London</div>
</div>
```